# What is the simplest way to order results from a SQL query on part of a string field in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sql-order-by

Consider a table with a text field with the following form:

```
"foo,bar"
```

EDITS:
"bar" is the first string after the comma.
There is only one comma.

What is the simplest way to order by `bar`? It can be in either SQL (PostgreSQL) or Ruby.

Comment: what is "bar"? Is it always the string starting at position 3? Or is it always the string after the first comma?

Comment: It is always the string after the first comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyTable.all.sort_by { |r| r.my_text.match(/,(.*)$/)[1] }
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. But why use relatively slow regex when split is enough: `my_text.split(',')[1]`

Comment: That's probably the right way to go @maprihoda, but @B Seven specified 'first string after the comma', not 'second comma separated field'. So above would match "foo,bar,baz" as "bar,baz", where `split[1]` would match "bar".

Comment: Actually, there is only one comma. Thanks.

Comment: @Mori So you are sorting the objects in memory. But what if there are many objects? Wouldn't that be slow and a memory hog?

Comment: @B Seven Can you ALTER the table? Add another column to it?

Comment: @maprihoda - Yes, I will ALTER the table. But for now I just want to change the order without ALTERing it. There are very few records anyway...

Comment: @maprihoda, yes. A SQL `order by` solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it inside the database like this:

```
M.order("substring(c from ',.*$')")
```

where `M` is your model and `c` is the column in question. The [`substring`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) call leaves the comma in the substring but that won't alter the sorting and comparing the commas during sorting will probably be faster than trying to remove them. Also, that form of PostgreSQL's `substring` [should work in 8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) so it should work with a Heroku shared database.

Comment: @BSeven: If you're doing this sort of thing all the time you could add an index on the result of that function call; you'd probably have to maintain that index by hand though, I don't think Rails migrations are up to the task (but maybe not).